# Ubuntu 13.04 not restarting

Tags: 13.04, virtualization

I installed 13.04 in Oracle VM on windows 8. It installed without any errors that I could see, but it fails to restart properly; it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try it in Virtualbox or VMWare Player?

The crashing on reboot could be caused by all sorts of things.